# Limit database concurrent connections in regard to web (http) requests

Tags: php, mysql, database-connection, httprequest

How can I, by using php, limit the number of incoming connections so it doesn't exceed 1000 (which I think will allow good performance for my small app) and just ask incoming users to wait x time if said number is reached?

So far the only thing I've come up with is to add a table with a number of connections and substract 1 when a user enters and when that counter reaches 0 then ask to wait, but I think there should be a better way.

Comment: I think you should seriously consider something like this because people don't like waiting if you ask me. If you get that big I think that is a good thing and you should consider buying more servers.

Answer (score 0):

HTTP is stateless, there is no such thing as a connection, per say. You need to have some sort of session handling system and limit it there.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using MySQL there is an option called [max_user_connections](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/user-resources.html) and [max_connections](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_connections)

But I'm not really sure if it is what you need, or how to know when the limit is reached.